# How to fragment a large python object into smaller chunks

Tags: python

I have an object in python- string of size ~3MB. I need to store this data in aerospike, for which am using llist. Now the problem is- individual element of the llist cannot exceed a particular limit- 200Kb. Is there a way to split a python string or byteArray into smaller chunks of a particular size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StringIO to read chunks of the string:

```
import random
import string
data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(100))

from io import StringIO

s = StringIO(data)
chunk = s.read(20)  # Set to 200KB
while chunk:
    print(chunk)    # Do something with chunk
    chunk = s.read(20)
```

Output:

```
BLAJHKDTRGALQUXHGVDR
MAQZTBARFZTYVVCNSSIR
NULVQTZFFLXEBHBLOJRR
PFEDLOSDSRHAYYXLAYBV
KSXPMGHDFJDLHGYEEWKD
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Consider this code:

`s="string"`

`list(s)` will yield `['s','t','r','i','n','g']`

You could also get individual characters by looping through the string:

```
for x in s:
   print x
```

If you wanted to split the string into smaller strings, that are larger than a single character, you could do something like this.

```
L=[]
n=5 #length of each string
for i in xrange(0,len(s),n):
    L.append(s[i:i+n])
```

Thhis will split s into several small strings of length n.